# How do I write a function?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add 2 arguments to a dialog box function. The first argument should be for the box title and the second should be for the box content. I'd like to call this function and set the box's title and body content on the fly.

Here is what I'd like the function to encompass:

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
 .html('This dialog will show every time!')
 .dialog({
   height   : 140,
   modal    : true,
   autoOpen : false,
   title    : 'Basic Dialog'
 });
```

This currently opens the dialog box.

```
$dialog.dialog('open');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your function:

```
function createDialog(title, content)
{
    return $('<div></div>')
        .html(content || 'Defualt content.')
        .dialog({
            height   : 140,
            modal    : true,
            autoOpen : false,
            title    : title || 'Defualt title'
        });
}
```

---

You can then call the function like this:

```
$dialog = createDialog('Basic Dialog', 'This dialog will show every time!');
```

and then open it with `$dialog.dialog('open')` as you have, or you can open it right away:

```
createDialog('Basic Dialog', 'This dialog will show every time!').dialog('open');
```

---

As pointed out by @LordZardeck, the above solution will result in too many stray DOM nodes. You're better off reusing the same dialog (is it safe to assume you'll only ever want one dialog at once? I sure hope so!).

If you wish to keep your DOM a little saner, try this:

```
var createDialog = (function($)
{
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>').dialog({
            height   : 140,
            modal    : true,
            autoOpen : false
        }),
        $content = $dialog.find('.dialog-content');

    return function (title, content)
    {
        $content.html(content || 'Default content.');

        return $dialog.dialog('option', {
                    title    : title || 'Defualt title'
                });
    }
})
(jQuery);
```

Usage is the same as with the one above.

Comment: Thank you! Will accept this after the (currently) 6 min wait.

Comment: I must say, that's a really ingenious solution! Props! And if you don't mind, i'll be modifying my code to use that!

Answer (score 3):

I have a custom alert that I use which I think works great. one reason it does, is that it deletes the dialog from the body when closed, making sure that you don't fill up your dom with a bunch of dialogs that won't get used again:

```
function showMessage(m, t)
{
    t = (t)? t : 'Application Message';
    return $('<div>').css({'text-align': 'left', 'padding-top': '10px'}).html(m).dialog({
            modal: true,  
            width: '400px',
            height: 140,
            title: t,
            autoOpen: false,
            close: function(){$(this).dialog('destroy');},
            buttons: { Ok: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you LordZardeck. In the spirit of fairness. Joseph Silber answered first but I wanted to thank you anyhow. I've voted up your answer because I used your destroy function. :)

Comment: +1  for taking into account the numerous DOM elements that might be created. However, why would you create and destroy the dialog over and over again? Why not simply reuse the same dialog?

Comment: true. while it probably is not going to affect that much in performance, we should always strive to better our code. here's the problem though, how can we define a global variable to assign it to and guarantee it won't interfere with other code?